# Differentiating $\frac{2t-4}{(t^2+2)^2}$ by the quotient rule?

Tags: calculus

The quotient rule $\frac{u}{v} = \frac{v\frac{du}{dx} - u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2}$

There comes a point where I need to differentiate my $v$ which is $(t^2+2)^2$, so when it comes to $\frac{dv}{dx}$ how do I go about this? Do I just expand the brackets like this $(t^2+2)(t^2+2) = t^4+2t^2+2t^2+4$ and then differentiate those terms and plug them back in the formula?

I found that the result is quite messy.

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Quotient rule is garbage. It shouldn't even be its own rule. It should be product rule and chain rule with $f \cdot 1/g$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

You can organize differentiation of a quotient/fraction in the following convenient way:

In a raster plug in  derivatives of numerator and denominator

$$\boxed{\left(\dfrac{u}{v}\right)'=\left(\dfrac{u}{v}-\dfrac{u'}{v'}\right) \cdot \dfrac{-v'}{v}}$$

Let $ t^2+2 =[]$.  Take out $2$ as common factor and plug into Raster

$$\left(\dfrac{t-2}{[]^2}- \dfrac{1}{4t}[] /[]^2\right)\cdot \left(\dfrac{-4t}{[]}\right)$$

with $[]^3$ in denominator, the  numerator is

$$ -(4t^2 -8t -t^2-2 )$$

results in

$$-2\dfrac{(3t^2-8t-2)}{[]^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can expand it that way if you want, or you can use the chain rule
$$\frac d{dt}(t^2+2)^2=2(t^2+2)\frac d{dt}(t^2+2)=2(t^2+2)\cdot 2t$$
which is the same as you got another way.  This approach is much easier for more complicated compositions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps-Final answer as followed [image]